# unable create new iframe using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, iframe

I am trying to create iframe in my project.

in JS

```
 function callPage(pagename)
     {
    $('<iframe>', { id:  'result1', frameborder: 0, scrolling: 'no'
         }).appendTo('.result2');
   document.getElementById("result1").src<%=ApplicationParams.getAppUrl()%>action/"+pagename;

 }
```

in JSP

```
 <div id="result2">
            </div>
```

Please suggested to me? what is wrong?

```
Error  : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null
```

Comment: try this `document.getElementById("result1").src = <%ApplicationParams.getAppUrl()%>action/"+pagename;` use the src value after the `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your append to is appending to a class, change to ID.

.appendTo('.result2');

->

.appendTo('#result2');